# why the image doesn't take the full height of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the image (any image) height equal the window height even when I resize, I want to do it by jquery.
I used **resize** method in jquery but I don't get the results I need.

html:

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
       width: 1200px;
       margin: auto;
}

.header {
background: url('https://preview.ibb.co/cu9YyH/download.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
        $(".header").height($(window).height());

        $(window).resize(function () {

            $(".header").height($(window).height());
        });
});
```

Comment: Share your HTML as well?

Comment: And your CSS if you have any.

Comment: okay @void and amflare

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for JS here. CSS alone will do the job, and is preferable for two reasons. Firstly this is a UI concern, so you shouldn't use JS as a crutch for that. Secondly, it performs better and you don't need to rely on  the `resize` event to update the settings on the element.

To achieve what you need use `vh` (viewport height) units, like this:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  I am the full-height header...
</header>
<div>
  Some content here...
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use jquery because I'm practicing
I edited the question

Comment: In that case you'll need to use `background-size: cover`: https://jsfiddle.net/qpud68m0/2/. Although I'd strongly suggest you always do this in CSS in a production environment